# add members of team to SfCalendar

Tags: flutter, dart

i am  [SfCalendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) package, to show all the meeting base on date, which is like
[image: this]

but now i have a list of members attached to the Meeting which i want to show at the bottom of the time.

here is my sample code

```
class _AllShiftState extends State<AllShift> {
  List<Meeting> _getDataSource() {
    final List<Meeting> meetings = <Meeting>[];
    final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    final DateTime startTime = DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 9);
    final DateTime endTime = startTime.add(const Duration(hours: 2));
    meetings.add(
      Meeting('Conference', startTime, endTime, const Color(0xFF0F8644), false,
          [""]),
    );
    return meetings;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SfCalendar(
        onTap: (va) {},
        view: CalendarView.schedule,
        appointmentTextStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
        ),
        dataSource: MeetingDataSource(_getDataSource()),
        monthViewSettings: const MonthViewSettings(
          appointmentDisplayMode: MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the class that extend the `CalendarDataSource`

```
class MeetingDataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  /// Creates a meeting data source, which used to set the appointment
  /// collection to the calendar
  MeetingDataSource(List<Meeting> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) {
    return _getMeetingData(index).from;
  }

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) {
    return _getMeetingData(index).to;
  }

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) {
    return _getMeetingData(index).eventName;
  }

  @override
  Color getColor(int index) {
    return _getMeetingData(index).background;
  }

  List<String> getMembers(int index) {
    return _getMeetingData(index).members;
  }

  @override
  bool isAllDay(int index) {
    return _getMeetingData(index).isAllDay;
  }

  Meeting _getMeetingData(int index) {
    final dynamic meeting = appointments![index];
    late final Meeting meetingData;
    if (meeting is Meeting) {
      meetingData = meeting;
    }

    return meetingData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detailed code?

Comment: @bakboem so i have a list of name which i want to show in the calendar after the conference